# How to bind spinner input value with a slider in primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, slider, spinner

I was implenting this example from primefaces [showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/slider.xhtml?jfwid=aa633) to provide `Spinner Slider` input, although I used the same code provided in the showcase, I faced a problem that spinner value is not synchronized with it's slider, if the value in the spinner input is e.g. `10`, when I change this value with the slider to e.g `50`, if I increment the spinner, I should expect value 51, but actually it gives me `11` as if it's value is independent from the slider

this is my XHTML code

```
<div class="card">
    <h:form>
        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true"/>
        <h5>Spinner Slider</h5>
        <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
            <p:spinner id="spinner1" value="#{sliderView.number3}" min="0" max="1000" stepFactor="50"
                       suffix=" €" valueChangeListener="#{sliderView.onInputChanged}">
                <p:ajax process="@this" update="growl"/>
            </p:spinner>
            <p:slider for="spinner1" minValue="0" maxValue="1000" step="50"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</div>
```

and `sliderView.java` is the same as the primefaces [showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/slider.xhtml?jfwid=aa633) example

here is a [GIF](https://media.giphy.com/media/pWAc7YOFOtUz0SgPtu/giphy.gif) that show an example

- Second problem, when I change the input from spinner, this doesn't change slider position, this is true even in the primefaces showcase, how to make the slider pointer change as the spinner value change

Comment: I've reported this issue https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/8298

Comment: Ok thanks, I find a workaround to produce the same behavior, I will post it as answer.

Comment: I faced 2 other issues, changing spinner from mouse wheel doesn't affect the backing bean, and style applied in the showcase didn't work in with me`(buttons="horizontal-after"
                           upButtonStyleClass="ui-button-success" downButtonStyleClass="ui-button-danger")`

Comment: @ibnSaadoosh you should report any bugs on the github issues page with Primefaces Test reproducers attached to the ticket proving the bug

Comment: @ibnSaadoosh style can be version related. What version and theme are you using?